# UIRefreshControl in a UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uirefreshcontrol

I have a `UIViewController` that has a `UITableView` as a `subView`. I am trying to add a pull-to-refresh on the table.
     I have the `UIRefresh` showing but it  never calls the selector. I am not getting notified that the pull action happened.
     I cannot use the `TableView` controller as i am using this View as my Generic View So that i can use for multiple View controllers

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad{

    [super viewDidLoad];

   // Refresh control
     UITableViewController *tableViewController = [[UITableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
tableViewController.tableView = self.genericMainTableView;

// Initialise refresh control
self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];

//Adding target to refresh Control object
[self.refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

//Setting attribute Title
self.refreshControl.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"Pull To Refresh"];

//Adding as subview to tableView
tableViewController.refreshControl  = self.refreshControl;

}

- (void)refresh:(UIRefreshControl *)refreshControl {

reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
NetworkStatus netStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];
//Not Reachable - No Internet Connection
if (netStatus == NotReachable) {
    [[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Network Error" message:@"Please Check your Network Connection" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil]show];
    [refreshControl endRefreshing];

}
else{

    //My Function Call
    [self functionCall];

    //Reload the Table
    [self.genericMainTableView reloadData];

    //set the title while refreshing
    refreshControl.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"Refreshing the TableView"];
    //set the date and time of refreshing
    NSDateFormatter *formattedDate = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [formattedDate setDateFormat:@"MMM d, h:mm a"];
    NSString *lastupdated = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Last Updated on %@",[formattedDate stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];
    refreshControl.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:lastupdated];

    //End Refreshing
    [refreshControl endRefreshing];
}
```

}

Am I doing everything right here. Its not working for me. Please Help me in this.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your viewDidLoad. No need to instantiate UITableViewController for refresh control. Just change viewDidLoad to this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{

[super viewDidLoad];

// Initialise refresh control
self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];

//Adding target to refresh Control object
[self.refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
//Setting attribute Title
self.refreshControl.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"Pull To Refresh"];

//Adding as subview to tableView
[self.genericMainTableView addSubview:self.refreshControl];

}
```

Comment: i am not using a UITableviewController thats why i did like that.i am using a UIViewController

Comment: No problem. See you have placed your table view in the view of this UIViewController and also made reference as self.genericMainTableView. So there is no need of that UITableViewController instantiation. Just replace above code and it will work. Hope so if rest of the things are correct.

Comment: It should work. Is your UITableView working properly? If yes then do one more trick. Just move addTarget line below the addSubview line.

Answer (score 0):

You have to initiate the `UIRefreshControl` in your `viewDidLoad` like this:

```
// Pull To Refresh Code
UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
[refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(handleRefresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Here is your selector `handleRefresh:`

```
-(void) handleRefresh:(UIRefreshControl *) refreshControl{
    [self performSelector:@selector(yourMethodHere)];
}
```

Also try to check that the reference to your selector is working or not. Click on your selector wile holding command button.

Comment: Thanks for the comment :) But i tried that too , but its not working.

Comment: Try renaming your selector then

Answer (score 0):

You just need a scorllview,and set refreshcontrol to it will do the trick.
Whatever controller you are in.